# Term for "elderly-sitter"?

Tags: single-word-requests

There's like people who do baby-sitting, that is look after infants and toddlers for the parents. What do we call people who do this for the elderly? For example, my friend hires a "elder-sitter" for her mother. It's not a professional, just someone who knows how to care for the elderly.

Is there a name for this person?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Caregiver is the professional term. I'm not certain if there is a less formal word.

> **[caregiver](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/caregiver?region=us)** |ˈkɛrˈgɪvər|
>   *noun*
>   a family member or paid helper who regularly looks after a child or a sick, elderly, or disabled person.

Comment: Welcome to English.SE!  Congratulations on your successful answer!

Answer (score 6):

[Carer](http://www.uk-care.com/roles-of-live-in-carers.html).

Comment: This is probably UK specific, in American English we would  use *Caregiver*.

Answer (score 2):

It can carry a slightly negative/mocking connotation,  but the closest term I've heard to what you're asking for is [*granny-sitter*](http://caregivingadvice.blogspot.com/2009/05/granny-sitter-in-car-accident.html).

(Others have given the more formal/polite terms such as *carer/caregiver*, though these might be taken to imply either a professional role, or a permanent duty due to family ties.)

Comment: This works, but not for elderly men so much.